# Maven: how to place resource file together with jar?

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I have \src\main\resources\logback.xml file. When I run `mvn package` it is placed into the jar by default. How do I make Maven place it next to jar, not inside?

**So, well, I just want Maven to copy the resource to the same folder where jar will be.**

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**No plugin definitions needed**, just edit the build resources:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <!-- regular resource processsing for everything except logback.xml -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>logback.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <!-- resource processsing with a different output directory
             for logback.xml -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>logback.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <!-- relative to target/classes
                 i.e. ${project.build.outputDirectory} -->
            <targetPath>..</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

**Reference:**

- [`process-resources`
  (Maven Book)](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-common-goals.html#lifecycle-sect-process-resources-phase)
- [`<build><resources>` (POM
  Reference)](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources)

Comment: In what `phase` are the resources being copied? In my case I use `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy a `war` file into the depending project - from there I want it to be loaded into the final `.jar` but I'd like to guarantee that I always take the latest build of that `war` file. Btw: The first link appears to be dead.

Comment: @displayname fixed link. and process-resources is the phase you are looking for.

Comment: Hello sir , how can i place the folders of resources folder under `src/main` in final jar ?

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS set `<resource><targetPath>` to the destination where you want your resources copied. See [docs](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Resource.html#setTargetPath(java.lang.String)).

Comment: thank you. but my question is how the jar file should be executed because resources cannot be found by using "java -jar file.jar"?

Comment: @epcpu you should ask that as a separate question

Comment: Note:  Remove the spring-boot plugin else it will create the file inside BOOT_INF

Answer (score 0):

You can build a ZIP file containing both using the [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/introduction.html).

You can also use [Maven Antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) or similar to put whatever file you want but the idea of single artifact per project is built deep into Maven internals so there is a chance it will hunt you down elsewhere.

Comment: I want to place them next to each other - resource next to jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude that file:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

And then use the Maven Antrun plugin to copy the file.

However, the latter part does not make much sense. If it is a configuration file to put in a server, simply manually copy it.

Comment: I just wanted to use Maven is a fully-powered build system to produce everything I need to deploy in a single click ;)