# how to create source.jar on maven install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm working in Sprint Tool Suite and I've created a maven project.  When I right click on the project I can select Run as...Maven Install.  This takes all my class files and packages them into a jar file as expected and also creates a copy to my central maven repository C:\Users\Owner.m2\repository

All that is fine, but I'd like it to also package up all the source files into a sources.jar file.  I suspect I'll need to edit the pom.xml file for the project to make that happen, but haven't seen an example of how to do that. Please advise.

Comment: You might want to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5730967/4039840)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add proper plugin to your execution cycle

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-sources</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```