# How to add a folder (and it's content) to the root of a Jar file with Maven in compile time?

Tags: java, maven

I need to copy the content of the example folder under : src/main/resources/example to the root of the generated jar file by maven

The problem seems to be with spring-boot-maven-plugin which generates this under BOOT-INF folder inside the jar.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <targetPath>example</targetPath>                           
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resource/example</directory>
    </resource>
</resource>
```

I expect the content under the example folder to be compiled to jar's root
Actual:
[Actual behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV5N1.png)

Comment: The answer of this SO thread [Maven: how to place resource file together with jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637532/maven-how-to-place-resource-file-together-with-jar) may solve your problem.

Comment: no lucky with this approach

Comment: this actually puts the file out of the jar

Comment: Please remove 'maven-plugin' tag. (Hover over a tag to see what it is for)

Answer (score 0):

Please remove any spring-boot plugin and only use resources tag as explained in the comment.

```
<resources>
 <resource>
   <targetPath>Where_you want_loc</targetPath>
</resource></resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of copy the folder to the JAR, why you don't acess the folder there where it is?

[Java: Acess and read all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/how-to-read-all-files-in-a-folder-from-java)

I hope this help you...

Comment: I need to add the content inside the jar in compile time for CI reasons